# Limitations on SQL Server stored procedures - multiple result sets / output parameters

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-logic-apps

I am unable to find limitations on stored procedure execution from Azure Logic Apps. I've seen that return values are not supported, and it was suggested to use output parameters to mitigate that.

The call result suggests output parameters to be supported but I can't get it to work:

Stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[TestOutputParameters]
    @paramIn AS INT,
    @errorCode INT = 0 OUTPUT,
    @errorMessage VARCHAR(255) = '' OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT @errorCode = @paramIn, @errorMessage = 'Some message'
    SELECT 'testing' AS abc     
    SELECT 'testing2' AS cde

    RETURN @errorCode
END
```

Running this locally yields the expected 2 result sets:

1. column abc with the value "testing"
2. column cde with the value "testing2"

and the expected output parameters `@errorCode` (value 5) and `@errorMessage` (value "Some message")

Azure Logic app step:

```json
"Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)": {
    "inputs": {
        "body": {
            "errorCode": "@variables('errorCode')",
            "errorMessage": "@variables('errorMessage')",
            "paramIn": 5
        },
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "post",
        "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[TestOutputParameters]'))}"
    },
    "runAfter": {
        "Initialize_variable_2": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "type": "ApiConnection"
}
```

The input body is

```json
"body": 
{
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorMessage": "",
    "paramIn": 5
}
```

The raw output is:

```json
"body": 
{
    "ResultSets": 
    {
        "Table1": 
        [
            {
                "abc": "testing"
            }
        ]
    },
    "OutputParameters": {}
}
```

The variables `@variables('errorCode')` and `@variables('errorMessage')` created before the stored procedure ran, remain unchanged, and only one result set is returned.

Is this a limitation of Azure Logic Apps? If so, is there a recommended workaround? If not, where is my mistake in calling the stored procedure?

Comment: The procedure is correct: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5QbyIZXr) Unfortunately I know nothing about Azure Logic Apps.

Comment: Maybe you need to define the parameter in `outputs` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#outputs

Comment: @Charlieface I don't believe the outputs definition applies here, I can't find a reference to this in the stored procedure description

Comment: Is the stored procedure in an on-prem server? _The following limitations apply to invoking a stored procedure on an on-premises SQL server: Output values for OUTPUT parameters aren't returned. You can still specify input values for OUTPUT parameters; Return value isn't available; Only the first result set is returned._ Ref: [General known issues and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/)

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning, I'll look at this and the answer and will report back. The SQL server is Azure as well; not on premises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with @AlwaysLearning if you use on prem, if not on prem then I have reproduced in my environment and below are the expected results:

**`Stored Procedure is:`**

```
CREATE or ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[TestOutputParameters]
    @paramIn AS INT
    ,@errorCode INT = 0 OUTPUT
    ,@errorMessage AS VARCHAR(255) OUTPUT 
AS BEGIN
    SELECT @errorCode = @paramIn, @errorMessage = 'Some message'
    SELECT 'testing' AS abc     
    SELECT 'testing2' AS cde
    RETURN @errorCode
END
```

[image]

**`Design which worked for me:`**

[image]

**`Schema`** for parse json is:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "body": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "errorCode": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "errorMessage": {
                    "type":[ "string","null"]
                },
                "paramIn": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then Sql Connector:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "errorCode": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['errorCode']",
                        "errorMessage": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['errorMessage']",
                        "paramIn": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['paramIn']"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[TestOutputParameters]'))}"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var",
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": {
                                "body": {
                                    "errorCode": 0,
                                    "errorMessage": "Rithwik",
                                    "paramIn": 8
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@variables('var')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "body": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "errorCode": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "errorMessage": {
                                        "type": [
                                            "string",
                                            "null"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "paramIn": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3=/resourceGroups/rbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
                    "connectionName": "sql",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try to follow above process you will get output as I have got, but if still you cannot get I would suggest you to raise a support request as evreything is correct in my flow.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this and try and figure it out. The SQL server is Azure as well, so not on premises.

Comment: Im sure it will work, as it worked in my case.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same result. OutputParameters {} is empty. I'll need to verify with my colleague what the SQL server actually is

Comment: The SQL server is on a virtual machine in Azure - would that count as on-premise as opposed to a pure Azure SQL instance?

Comment: I am partially inclined to say yes as  its not fully managed by Paas database like Azure SQL database and is maintained by VM, but the way i have given is correct. and it gives correct output too.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as I'm sure it's correct; I'll test against an Azure SQL again to check the difference. I suppose that SQL on a VM is on-premise in a way.